# NPM version incompatible with node version

Tags: node.js, npm, debian

I am currently using Node.js on Debian 10. I was trying to upgrade my node and npm versions so that I can deploy to firebase, because the firebase commands apparently are no longer compatible with the node version I was using. I ran `npm install -g npm` to upgrade npm. Now, every time I try to do an npm install, I get this error:

```
ERROR: npm v9.2.0 is known not to run on Node.js v12.22.12. You'll need to
upgrade to a newer Node.js version in order to use this version of npm. This
version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 ||
>=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

ERROR:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exit-handler.js:22
  const hasLoadedNpm = npm?.config.loaded
                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:76:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

But when I run `npm -v`, I still get `7.5.2`, which is the version of npm that I had before. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both node and npm (using sudo apt-get remove and sudo apt-get install), but the issue still persists.

How do I revert back to my old npm version? (7.5.2)

Comment: Had a similar problem using WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS). Turned out there was a non-apt managed npm library under `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. Try and see what `which npm` returns. Removing that folder and installing an up-to-date version of npm using `apt install` fixed the OP problem for me. HTH

Answer (score 1):

**Check for Multiple Node.js Versions:**

You can check if you have multiple Node.js versions installed on your system by running the following commands:

```
node -v

sudo /usr/bin/node --version.
```

If you get different versions, it's likely that Node.js was installed from different sources.

**Solution:**

**1.Uninstall Existing Node.js:**

```
sudo apt remove nodejs
```

**2.Install nvm:**

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc
```

**3.Install nodejs using nvm:**

```
nvm install --lts
```

**4.Create a Symlink for System-Wide Access:**

To make the nvm-managed Node.js version accessible system-wide, create a symlink in a system directory like /usr/local/bin (commonly included in the system's PATH):

a. Find the path to the nvm-managed Node.js binary:

```
which node
```

b. Create a symlink to that binary in a system directory like /usr/local/bin, which is typically included in the system's PATH:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/nvm/node /usr/local/bin/node
```

Replace /path/to/nvm/node with the actual path to the nvm-managed Node.js binary.

**5.Verify Installation**

Confirm that Node.js is correctly installed and accessible both as your regular user and with sudo:

```
node -v
sudo node -v
```

Both commands should display the same Node.js version.

Comment: did you use any AI at all to write any part of this answer?